# Emsdk script fails to run on Windows 10

Tags: python, webassembly, emscripten, emsdk

I'm trying to get started with *Emscripten*. I'm following [the official guideline](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#sdk-download-and-install), but fail to succeed. The `emsdk` script just outputs `Python` to whatever I type in and seems to stay idle:

```
D:\VSProjects\EmscriptenGuide\emsdk>emsdk install latest
Python
D:\VSProjects\EmscriptenGuide\emsdk>emsdk activate latest
Python
D:\VSProjects\EmscriptenGuide\emsdk>emsdk
Python
D:\VSProjects\EmscriptenGuide\emsdk>emsdk blah blah blah
Python
D:\VSProjects\EmscriptenGuide\emsdk>
```

I have my python 3.9.5 executable in the `PATH` environment variable. I also tried to specify it explicitly when running the script, but it didn't change anything. Am I doing something wrong?