# How does emsdk (a bash script) works on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, powershell-core

I was following emsdk installation guide: https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html#sdk-download-and-install

And come across this suspicious line:

```bash
# Download and install the latest SDK tools.
./emsdk install latest
```

To my great surprise, it works without any issue in my windows machine. I was using pwsh7.
The script is clearly a bash script: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emsdk/blob/main/emsdk

```bash
PS C:\Intermediate\Projects\emsdk> .\emsdk install latest
Resolving SDK alias 'latest' to '3.1.47'
Resolving SDK version '3.1.47' to 'sdk-releases-39ade279e75e6d17dd6b7eb9fba2006e61fe966b-64bit'
Installing SDK 'sdk-releases-39ade279e75e6d17dd6b7eb9fba2006e61fe966b-64bit'..
Installing tool 'node-16.20.0-64bit'..
Downloading: C:/Intermediate/Projects/emsdk/downloads/node-v16.20.0-win-x64.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/webassembly/emscripten-releases-builds/deps/node-v16.20.0-win-x64.zip, 28623474 Bytes
Unpacking 'C:/Intermediate/Projects/emsdk/downloads/node-v16.20.0-win-x64.zip' to 'C:/Intermediate/Projects/emsdk/node/16.20.0_64bit'
Done installing tool 'node-16.20.0-64bit'.
...
```

Even on the installation guide page it says `On Windows, run emsdk.bat instead of ./emsdk, and emsdk_env.bat instead of source ./emsdk_env.sh.` But the question here is how come the `./emsdk` script works in the first place?

This question is related to [Emsdk script fails to run on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76226500/emsdk-script-fails-to-run-on-windows-10), where OP's environment cannot execute that file properly.

It even works in cmd:

```bash
C:\Intermediate\Projects\emsdk>emsdk install latest
Resolving SDK alias 'latest' to '3.1.47'
Resolving SDK version '3.1.47' to 'sdk-releases-39ade279e75e6d17dd6b7eb9fba2006e61fe966b-64bit'
Installing SDK 'sdk-releases-39ade279e75e6d17dd6b7eb9fba2006e61fe966b-64bit'..
Skipped installing node-16.20.0-64bit, already installed.
Skipped installing python-3.9.2-nuget-64bit, already installed.
Skipped installing java-8.152-64bit, already installed.
Skipped installing releases-39ade279e75e6d17dd6b7eb9fba2006e61fe966b-64bit, already installed.
All SDK components already installed: 'sdk-releases-39ade279e75e6d17dd6b7eb9fba2006e61fe966b-64bit'.
```

I wonder how on earth can it work without a problem? Because apparently non of the syntax is recognizable in windows in CMD (here I am executing the first line from the emsdk bash script in CMD directly):

```bash
C:\Intermediate\Projects\emsdk>PYTHON3="$(dirname "$0")/python/3.9.2-1_64bit/bin/python3"
'PYTHON3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: In case someone is not sure, Windows has no support for Shebang whatsoever, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574453/shebang-notation-python-scripts-on-windows-and-linux

Comment: I suspect that when I type `emsdk` in either cmd or powershell terminal, it's actually executing (by default) emsdk.ps1 or emsdk.bat behind the scene.

Comment: Did you look at the first few lines of the code? Seems most likely that is how it decides how to proceed. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I looked at it and the syntax is not cmd or ps1.

Comment: My Powershell (untouched in Win 10 since it was installed 9 months ago), prompted me *"Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6"* , :Cross-platform seems like a possible explanation, but I am (obvously) not a PS person. I tried `winget search` with `pscore(6,7),  Powershell, cross-platform, pwsh7` and couldn't find anything to install to see this for myself. Any ideas? Tnx